# separate values/strings.xml android

Tags: android

I am new here.

How do we go about separating the string values for different categories(fragments,activity, etc.)

For now I put everything in one file,that is the values/strings.xml. When the program gets too big, they are all jumbled together and hard to differentiate.

any advice?

thanks,
techfang

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

The filename is arbitrary. You can name your strings files as you want strings_my_activity for example

Comment: R use the xml tag to generate the R.string.xxx and not the file name (that would be a pain in the ***), so you can name those anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give each string a **meaningful** name, haha. Then, have them listed in section, use newlines to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple string resource files, so it is perfectly allowable for you to have (for example):

```
res/
    strings.xml
    main_activity_strings.xml
    main_fragment_strings.xml
    sub_fragment_strings.xml
```

The files themselves can have any allowable name really.  What is important is what is in the file.  So any  entry ends up resolving to R.string.xxxxxxx

How desirable this approach is, is of course another question.  You may find you want to keep 'global' strings (such as OK, Cancel, etc.) in the top-level strings.xml file.